# Integrating PayPal Rest API to website

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal, e-commerce

I built an e-commerce site for a client with a custom cart, and shopping experience and now it's time to integrate a payment method. He wants to use Paypal. I have been messing around with Paypal trying to get it to work for hours now and cannot seem to figure it out.

First attempt - I made a custom Paypal button using html that fills in the variables using PHP to come up with pricing and item details. This worked fine but I need to get a response from Paypal once the payment is successful so I can handle the details on my website which I couldn't figure out how to do making a custom button.

Second attempt - I am now trying to use this tutorial to use the Paypal REST API:
http://earlysandwich.com/programming/php/integrate-paypal-rest-api-using-php-294/

I understand all the steps in the tutorial. The error I am getting when running create.php is:
Fatal error: Class 'ApiContext' not found in /bootstrap.php on line 4

So I figured it's because I don't have the Paypal API included in my project.
I downloaded the Paypal API from here https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/releases
(as I don't understand how to use 'composer' or CURL or any of those things :(  )

I uploaded it onto my server under the folder /PayPal-PHP-SDK

I went back to my /bootstrap.php file and put the following line of code:
require './PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php';

I am still getting the same Fatal error.

Is this the way I should be going about getting Paypal included or is there an easier way? I simply need to pass an amount to Paypal & get a response if the payment was successful.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to easily get started, and resolve ApiContext class not found issue by following instructions in the wiki page: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki

We have [Installation Guide](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Installation), with or without composer, and [steps to make your first call](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call), that should get you started very very quickly.

Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Is this works in woocommerce website?